# What's "Swedish" style of doing type theory or proof assistants?

Tags: terminology

Jon Sterling [said](https://github.com/RedPRL/redtt/issues/113#issue-333172244) Conor McBride's universe polymorphism proposal to be:

> seems to have worked well in Swedish experiments

I wonder, what does "Swedish" mean here? What kind of type theory or Proof Assistant practice is considered Swedish? Are there other styles (my guess would be French, but I'm unsure)?

Comment: "Swedish" means that it was done by Thierry Coquand.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Does that mean Coq is kinda Swedish (I used 'kinda' because Thierry Coquand is not the only author)? I thought it would be considered French

Comment: Well, I mean, there are other people in Sweden who do type theory, for instance Andreas Abel, Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine and Taichi Uemura, to name a few.

Comment: Coq is from the French tradition, despite Thierry Coquand now living in Sweden. I'd contrast the Swedish-Scottish tradition (whose defining feature is reluctance at impredicativity) with the French-Dutch one (whose defining feature is that they allegedly work in a system not grounded in philosophy but raw string substitution).

Comment: There are more subtle differences, one is Curry-style (in the Swedish school) vs Church-style (in the French one) abstractions, another is definitely untyped conversion à la PTS (French tradition) vs much more typed conversion à la MLTT (Swedish tradition).

Comment: Another notable difference is that the French use humor when naming their proof assistants.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand The Swedish tradition is today characterized by fully typed representations, usually generalized algebraic, so it would not be right to say that the Swedish tradition is Curry-style. (Even though for a several years i in the 1970s-1980s Per Martin-Loef was doing things that some people might call Curry-style.)

Comment: @JonathanSterling By Curry-style I mean having a (pre)-syntax with unannotated abstractions. Indeed, you can build such a syntax as intrinsically typed, in which case you implicitly record all the typing information, and I agree it does not qualify as Curry-style any more. But I do not think everybody in the "Swedish" tradition does this. I’m thinking for instance about the proof of decidability  of conversion by Abel et al. at POPL18, or the implementations of Agda or Epigram, which I think belong to that tradition and afaik do not follow the fully-typed approach.

Comment: For me, Peter Dybjer is the Guardian of Swedish Type Theory.